# How can I make an item selectable only once in Vaadin ComboBox?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I have several ComboBoxes in Vaadin that all access the same DataSource.

I want the following behaviour:

- Initially all boxes are empty. I select an item in the first box.
- In the second box I do not want the item to show up that I chose in
  the first box.

I tried to add a filter to the underlying datasource to only pass items that have not been selected yet. However this solution does not work since the selected item disappears as soon as it is selected (since it is filtered out from the datasource)

How can I achieve my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Create separate data sources for each ComboBox and filter out the selected items only for the next ComboBoxes.

Comment: Going to try this monday. Thanks already for the suggestion I really think this could work.